# Magento re-order button for ALL customers (also guest), simple copy order details

Tags: orders, customer, backend, sales, sales-order

I would like to +1 this thread: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/40273/#t428770

This quote from 'egyember' sums it up

> To be honest the reorder button would be very useful on Guest orders as we could just copy all the customer details (name, email,
>   address) onto the new order. Currently, you have to manually copy over
>   the details from the previous order.

**Question:** How can we add a re-order button on order-level, that does one thing only: copy all the order details to a new order.

(would be a simple and I think great extension)

Many thanks

Comment: Looking for the same solution. I'll answer this question if I've worked out a way to do this. It should be relatively easy in theory to create an extension to do this.

Comment: Good to know @Blair let us know what you find. Saw some of your replies in other forum.